# Do we need "CSS reset" for mobile browsers also?

Tags: xhtml, html, css, mobile-website

Do we need "CSS reset" for mobile specific site also? like we need for desktop browsers?

Can css reset on mobile sites decrease the performance of rendering?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How strongly do you believe in CSS reset for the desktop?

I tend to agree with those who argue that CSS resets are too heavy-handed (have you ever read one?  I'd never heard of some of those elements) and that ultimately, hand-crafted rules based on your actual needs will be most predictable and efficient.

The mobile platform only makes bandwidth even more precious.  I guess that's why you're asking.  I'd say, whittle a standard reset down to what you really need.

Comment: +1. The number of commonly-used elements that really need their default rules altered in modern browsers is quite low, assuming one is using Standards Mode (and one certainly should be). I find most CSS resets massively over-heavy.

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting must modern smartphones like Android or iPhone devices, a CSS reset isn't too helpful because there isn't that much variation there.  However, the overall mobile browser scene now is pretty chaotic.  There is so much variation among the browser types, browser versions, operatiing systems, screen sizes and resolution, etc.  I believe a CSS reset helps provide a better starting point for your styles and will help avoid headaches down the road.