# Is CSS reset recommended for Mobile browsers?

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios, ipad

While I do understand what a CSS reset does, my question is more in context of implementing layouts which would be cross-browser, cross-platform compliant. E.g. layout should look similar on desktop browsers like ie, firefox and even on iPad and to some extent on iPhone as well.

Is CSS Reset recommended for implemeting layouts on mobile browsers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile devices use a web browser just like all other platforms, albeit with modifications suited to that device e.g. touch functionality. As such, a reset is still applicable on mobile platforms as the browser will still have default styles that you may want to overwrite.
However, it can be useful to leave the mobile's default styles in as the emphasis will then be on the content, and how it is best displayed in that mobile devices browser. You can then add to the default styles as you see fit.

Here is a reference to another answer of the same question here on stack:
[Do we need "CSS reset" for mobile browsers also?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730165/do-we-need-css-reset-for-mobile-browsers-also)

Answer (score 2):

I still reset styles on my mobile sites, but I write my own to minimise the file size.

Keeping the reset stylesheet small by resetting only the elements you're actually using is good practice for all websites, but particularly important for mobile sites.